# Wordpress: how to add new class "active" if the current wordpress slug id is use?

Tags: wordpress, tags

I have 2 div tag group; one is the Local Form and the other one is the International Form. My goal is to active or display the one form depending on the current slug id echoed on the class.

I successfully get the current slug id and placed it in my class, but the problem was all 2 form are displayed.

the slug name are:
"local" and
"international"

```
<div id="app">
    <?php
      $tags = get_the_tags( $post->ID, 'post');     
         foreach ( $tags as $tag){
            echo '<div id="form" class="'.$tag->slug.' **I like to add active class here**">' 
    ?>  
    <h3><span><?php the_title(); ?></span><br>Local Application Form</h3>
    ..FORM DISPLAY HERE..   
    <?php '</div>';  ?>
    <?php  }  ?>                    
</div>

<div id="app">
    <?php
      $tags = get_the_tags( $post->ID, 'post');     
         foreach ( $tags as $tag){
            echo '<div id="form" class="'.$tag->slug.' **I like to add active class here**">' 
    ?>  
    <h3><span><?php the_title(); ?></span><br>International Application Form</h3>
    ..FORM DISPLAY HERE..   
    <?php '</div>';  ?>
    <?php  }  ?>                    
</div>

--CCS STYLE---
.local {
    display: none;
}
.local .active {
    display: block!important;
}

.international {
    display: none;
}
.international .active {
    display: block!important;
}


---OUTPUT GOAL----
<div id="form" class="local active"></div>
<div id="form" class="international"></div>
```

If the slug id "local" is currently use and has active class it will display to block, and the international form will display to none.

If the slug id "international" is currently use has active class it will display to block, and the local form will display to none.

Basically through php or javascript will get the current slug id and generate a new class called "active" to add in to new class.

Comment: Ids must be unique and your `class` attribute is missing its double quotes.

Comment: hi thank you for your message. this code are fine. I just like to put "active" class next to echoed current slug name on the class attribute

Comment: how I add "active" class base on the current slug value using javascript?

Comment: `this code are fine` You've fixed the double quote issue but you are still using the same id multiple times. Why isn't there any javascript in your question if you want to use javascript? What **exactly** do you want to achieve?

Comment: thank you. how could I add "active" class base on the current slug value using javascript?

Comment: Why javascript? The slug is not going to change while the page is displayed to the user, is it? Add a conditional statement in PHP.

Comment: thank you. I don't have idea. my only thing running in my mind is javascript since javascript can able to put additional class as active.  can you share your php codes how to achieve the goal?

Comment: Your goal is still unclear to me.

Comment: i don't think based on slug you can use div class. 
however just a suggestion, it might help you to achieve your goal. you can add div class based on your category name or id.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it, but I already used the category to other function. slug is the only way I can use it.

Comment: I added new details and code to my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out how I can put additional active class when current slugs is used by using terms in php

```
$terms = get_terms([
  'taxonomy' => 'taxonomyname',
  'hide_empty' => false,
 ]);
   foreach( $terms as $term ){
     $active = "";
       if($term_id == $term->term_id) {                                                 
     $active = "active";                                               
   }
   echo '<div id="form" class="'.$tag->slug.''.$active.'"></div>';                                                                                
}
```